# Synchronize Nodes within the same NodeGroup in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I have a symmetricds configuration where there are two Node Groups.

1. Server : has a static ip
2. Stores (have two nodes) : Don't have static ips, hence they push data to the server using server's sync url and pulls updates from the server. (No sync url is configured for nodes in this group as they don't have static ips)

The setup works fine, in following cases.

1. When data is added directly to Server (not from a Store node) they get updated in two Stores nodes
2. When data is added to one of the Stores, they push those to Server node.

My problem is in 2nd case above, the data that was added to one store doesn't sync to the other store though data get updated fine at the server. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those tables declare triggers for [bi-directional synchronization](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.6/user-guide/html-single/user-guide.html#bi-direction-sync) using SYNC_ON_INCOMING_BATCH set to 1.